# jackx PGX scan error - converting driver.Value type time.Time to a int: invalid syntax Golang Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, pgx

I get a scan error after inserting a row into the database. Below is my database structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "email" varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  "first_name" varchar NOT NULL,
  "last_name" varchar NOT NULL,
  "hashad_password" varchar NOT NULL,
  "active" bigint NOT NULL,
  "roll_id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
  "updated_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
  "password_changed_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);
```

And Below is Golang code.

```
var newID int
    stmt := `INSERT INTO users (email, first_name, last_name, hashad_password, active, roll_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) returning id`

    err = db.QueryRow(stmt,
        user.Email,
        user.FirstName,
        user.LastName,
        hashedPassword,
        user.Active,
        user.RollId,
    ).Scan(&newID)

    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
```

But every time I get a blow scan error.

```
sql: Scan error on column index 7, name "password_changed_at": converting driver.Value type time.Time ("2023-11-13 06:06:52.223458 +0000 UTC") to a int: invalid syntax
```

The row is inserted into the database successfully.

Thanks All

Comment: The code in the question does NOT cause the error. The shared code scans only one column (the returned `id`); the error `Scan error on column index 7` means that the code that causes the error is scanning 6 or more columns. More specifically, the query that is scanning those 6-or-more columns, is trying to scan the `password_changed_at` column into a variable of type `int`, but the column's source value is of type `time.Time` (since you declared that column as `timestamptz`), hence the error.

Comment: Yes, and I have tried all but nothing works it scans more than 6 rows because the table has 10 rows and all datatype already mentioned in the migrate SQL file and it works fine. The code also inserts a row into the database but does not return id of it and gives an error. I haven't specified or used the `password_changed_at` column in inserting and I don't think any other code affects this one.

Comment: Sorry but you're not making any sense. The code in the question IS NOT causing the quoted error. Please update the question to include the code that's causing the error.

Comment: https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/authentication-service/data/models.go

Here is the repo.

Comment: 8th column (i.e. column on index 7) [here](https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/authentication-service/data/models.go#L129) is `password_changed_at` of type `timestampz`. 8th field (i.e. field with index 7) [here](https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/authentication-service/data/models.go#L144) is `Active` of type `int`. You CANNOT scan `TIMSTAMPZ` into `INT`.

Comment: Your other select queries are also not ordered correctly. The order of the selected columns DOES NOT MATCH the order of scanned fields.

Comment: Is it clear now? Do you see where the error in your code is?

Comment: Right now I am using only the [Insert function](https://github.com/GirishBhutiya/gocomm-micro/blob/main/authentication-service/data/models.go#L230) and I think there is no issue related to order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255931/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-girish-bhutiya).